# Losing My Mind Cause Fetching Core data always Return Fault

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Okay, straight to the point...

this is first time i use Magical record From Magical Panda
i've following tutroial from http://yannickloriot.com/2012/03/magicalrecord-how-to-make-programming-with-core-data-pleasant/

and here's my code

Person.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * age;
```

AppDelegate.M

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[JASidePanelController alloc] init];
    self.viewController.shouldDelegateAutorotateToVisiblePanel = NO;
  //  self.viewController = [[[ViewControllerCenter alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.viewController.centerPanel = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[ViewControllerCenter alloc] init]];

    //UINavigationController *navContorller=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.viewController.rightPanel = [[NetraRightWindow alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{


    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
     [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

this is my method to do saving :

```
-(void)fetchRecords{

   NSManagedObjectContext *localContext= [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];

    // Create a new Person in the current thread context
    Person *person                          = [Person MR_createInContext:    [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
    person.firstname                        = @"Test";
    person.lastname                         = @"merdeka123";
    person.age=[NSNumber numberWithInt:123];

    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_save];
    NSArray *Result=[Person MR_findAll];

    NSLog(@"Result==%@",Result);
```

and the result::

```
2012-11-25 15:43:38.033 Trip[10491:15e03] Cok==(
    "<Person: 0x866fe40> (entity: Person; id: 0x866e170 <x-coredata://15583C03-3EB4-479B-9EF2-B0BC750FC987/Person/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Person: 0x866fe80> (entity: Person; id: 0x8670210 <x-coredata://15583C03-3EB4-479B-9EF2-B0BC750FC987/Person/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Person: 0x81471a0> (entity: Person; id: 0x815c2a0 <x-coredata://15583C03-3EB4-479B-9EF2-B0BC750FC987/Person/p3> ; data: {\n    age = 123;\n    firstname = Test;\n    lastname = merdeka123;\n    time = nil;\n})"
)
```

why its always data fault? is that a problems in magical record? or any wrong in my code?

Comment: Faulting may sound like a bad thing, but it's actually an optimization for core data property fetches on managed objects.

Comment: is that any way to show the data on NSLOG?

Comment: The traditional way is to use `-valueForKey:` to actually get data, and not faults, but I haven't used magical record enough to give you an acceptable solution.

Comment: :(
this is followong tutorials http://yannickloriot.com/2012/03/magicalrecord-how-to-make-programming-with-core-data-pleasant/

Comment: I hate to tell you, man, but the Internet is wrong a lot. :P. maybe play around with this stuff yourself before going to some random website for development tutorials.  Besides, it's not like you get your head cut off for throwing an exception every once in a while.

Comment: LOL.. okay man... do you have an IM?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20059/discussion-between-netra-and-codafi)

Answer (score 7):

This isn't an error - it is a feature of Core Data called 'faulting'. Here is [Apple's description](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html):

> Faulting reduces the amount of memory your application consumes. A
>   fault is a placeholder object that represents a managed object that
>   has not yet been fully realized, or a collection object that
>   represents a relationship:
>
> A managed object fault is an instance of the appropriate class, but
>   its persistent variables are not yet initialized. A relationship fault
>   is a subclass of the collection class that represents the
>   relationship. Faulting allows Core Data to put boundaries on the
>   object graph. Because a fault is not realized, a managed object fault
>   consumes less memory, and managed objects related to a fault are not
>   required to be represented in memory at all.

If you want to see each Person object then you will have to specifically access them.

Comment: @sosborn... but they say if i want to see each person just type:   NSArray *Result=[Person MR_findAll];

    NSLog(@"Result==%@",Result);

Comment: Access one of the attributes of that result, not just the relationship.

Comment: @sosborn so CoreData only perform faulting for relationship, not for property of entity, right ? See http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started **However, with Core data you cannot retrieve only certain attributes of an object – you have to retrieve the entire object**

Comment: @entropy - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262024/is-it-possible-to-fetch-only-selected-property-in-a-core-data-query

Comment: @sosborn I've already looked at that question, but still don't understand

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting fault all the time in Magical records. After lots of headbanging.

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

if (!success) {

NSLog(@"::: Error saving context :::");

}

}];
```

Now when you do findAll. check the objects by printing in the debugger.

```
Person *testObject = [Result objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", testObject.firstname);
```

This should print your result in debugger.