# Getting specific attributes from coredata swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a request for an entity in core data:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Constants")

    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Within the entity `Constants` there are 4 attributes: `moneyPerSecondSave`,`moneySave`,`tapMultiplierSave`and`tapValueSave`.
My question is, is there a way that after I have got the `results` can I make four variables which each hold each of the values of the attributes.

I have already tried using `valueForKey`:

```
moneyConstants.money = results.valueForKey("moneySave")
```

However when I try this it pulls up an error: `Value of type '[AnyObject]' has no member 'valueForKey'. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `results` is an *array* ...

Comment: @MartinR So if i were to make a variable with `results[0]` it would presumably give me the value of the first attribute? Sorry if that is a stupid question, I'm new to swift.

Comment: That has little to do with Swift, more with Core Data (so you might want to read the Core Data Programming Guide). – `results` is an array of managed objects. If you created only one object then the array contains exactly one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'results' is an array which holds 'Any' type. You can cast it to an array with the type you expect and get the rest of the data like this:

```
     if let constants = results as? [Constants] {
            let moneyPerSecond = constants[0].moneyPerSecondSave
            print("moneyPerSecond: \(moneyPerSecond)")
        }
```

You can also use valueForKey of course, like this:

```
        if let match = results[0] as? Constants {
            let money = match.value(forKey: "moneySave") as! Float
            print("money: \(money)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `propertiesToFetch` & `resultType` attribute of `NSFetchRequest` to retrieve only specific property values of `Constants`.
You can take inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6267875/3339346